# sono io / sei tu: analisi logica

Tags: grammar, grammatical-analysis

Se io busso alla porta di casa di un amico, alla sua domanda "chi è?" risponderò "sono io". In inglese l'equivalente è "it's me" ("la persona dietro la porta è me"), dove è chiaro che "it" è soggetto, "is" predicato, e "me" è.. predicato nominale?
In italiano, essendo che "sono" è il verbo, "io" deve essere il soggetto. Ma è corretta così l'analisi logica?

Secondo esempio: guardando un vecchio album di foto, posso indicare un neonato in foto, e dire a mio figlio "questo sei tu": come funziona l'analisi? Se "sei" è il predicato, "tu" soggetto... "questo" cosa è? 
Suppongo che sarebbe predicato nominale se la frase fosse "tu sei questo", ma qui è diverso.
E di nuovo in inglese troviamo una meno ambigua "this is you".

Forse è un dubbio sciocco, ma ormai mi sono svegliata con questa domanda in testa

Comment: In attesa di risposte più autorevoli, a me sembra proprio che quegli “io” e “tu” siano soggetti. È tutta la frase che, per sottolineare qualcosa, è costruita in un modo diverso dal classico schema soggetto-predicato. Pensa a una frase in cui si parli di certe case e si dica “Le ha costruite Tizio”: il soggetto è senz'altro Tizio, no? E anche se nei tuoi esempi i predicati sono nominali e non verbali come qui, non cambia nulla. (Pensa per esempio a “Sai chi le ha costruite?” “Sì, è stato Tizio”.)

Comment: sí, suppongo siano soggetti. La domanda era piú per capire se l'anailisi logica distingua queste frasi da "io sono" e "tu sei questo", che sono frasi del tutto diverse. 
Se io dico "Le ha costruite Tizio" o "Tizio ha costruito queste case", la frase siginifica la stessa cosa. 

E mi resta il dubbio di cosa sia "Questo" in "Questo sei tu".

Mi rendo conto adesso che la domanda era scritta in modo un po' confuso ^^

Comment: Che differenza trovi fra “Questo sei tu” e “Tu sei questo”, oltre alla diversa enfasi sui diversi componenti della frase?

Comment: In effetti hai ragione, si puó usare "tu sei questo" anche nel contesto descritto. É che lo stavo pensando come "tu sei la tal cosa" (tu sei dottore, tu sei alto, ecc)

Comment: Un “errore“ comune in questi casi è *questo sei te*, dove il soggetto posposto è percepito come un caso indiretto per la sola posizione. Ma non c'è dubbio che *questo sei tu* ha *tu* come soggetto e *questo* come predicato nominale. L'ordine non ha importanza in questa analisi, ne ha per stabilire su quale parte della frase sia l'enfasi maggiore.

Comment: @LisaD Attenta all'uso scorretto dell'accento acuto.

Comment: @horcrux: chiedo scusa per gli accenti: è perché uso una tastiera inglese, che li fa solo acuti, e per fare gli accenti gravi devo ogni volta ricordarmi di copiarli e incollarli.

Comment: @LisaD Capito, nessun problema, credevo invece fosse questione di disabitudine al loro corretto uso.

Comment: @LisaD OT, ma consiglio vivamente la [tastiera americana con tasti muti](http://www.starr.net/is/type/intlchart.html). Io la trovo superiore persino alla tastiera italiana per scrivere l'italiano.

Comment: @DenisNardin a me la tastiera italiana non piace proprio: dovrebbe essere fatta per la lingua italiana, e non si possono fare le lettere maiuscole accentate. La cosa mi urta :D

Answer (score 5):

L'inversione di soggetto e verbo non cambia mai la natura del soggetto. Se dici

> oggi vado io

non avresti alcun dubbio che *io* è il soggetto. La frase potrebbe essere detta in un contesto in cui c'è un compito quotidiano da svolgere a turno e, per esempio, oggi non toccherebbe a me, ma ci vado al posto di qualcun altro. Il soggetto posposto dà un'enfasi particolare che non si avrebbe nel caso di *io vado oggi* (che potrebbe invece implicare un *e tu vai domani*).

In italiano il pronome soggetto è spesso omesso; solo in alcuni casi è necessario e uno è la risposta alla domanda “chi è?”. La risposta potrebbe essere solo *io*, sottintendendo il verbo.

Dunque *sono io* ha *io* come soggetto e non potrebbe essere altrimenti. In questo caso l'inversione è normale in molte varietà di italiano, ma *Montalbano sono*  ci dice che non è così dappertutto.

Nell'esempio di *questo sei tu* l'inversione pone l'enfasi in modo diverso da *tu sei questo* che potrebbe essere il caso in cui nella fotografia ci sono più bambini e la madre ne indica uno. Non cambia il fatto che *tu* è il soggetto e *sei questo* il predicato nominale. Non a tutti questo è chiaro, tanto che è frequente sentire qualcosa come *questo sei te*, dove il soggetto posposto è forse percepito come un caso indiretto.

A volte si ha l'inversione anche con un verbo transitivo: *il pane lo compri tu*. Qui però appare un pronome pleonastico che nell'analisi logica non andrebbe da nessuna parte: *il pane* è il complemento oggetto, *compri* il predicato verbale e *tu* il soggetto. O forse è semplicemente un anacoluto: *il pane, lo compri tu* e, su questo, l'analisi logica non può aprire bocca.